# How to redirect the logger of Bokeh Server (or any child process) to a file within Node?

Tags: python, node.js, logging, bokeh, child-process

I would like to run the bokeh server as a child process with Node. I would like to use the [`python_shell`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/python-shell) package and redirect the output in real-time, not at the end of the execution.

Bokeh does not have a configuration file or argument where I can write the logger file path. So I need to use [command redirection operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) in order to reroute the logger:

```
'>> `${debug_path}` 2>&1'
```

So I have tried some things:

```js
process.chdir(`${path}`);  // path where I should run bokeh

var options = {
mode: 'json',
pythonPath: `${python_path}`,
pythonOptions: [
        '-m', 'bokeh', 'serve',
    ],
    args: [
        '>>', `${debug_path}`, '2>&1',   // this is not working, in pythonOptions neither
    ]
};

python_shell.run('', options, function (err, results) {
    if (err) {
        logger.error(`${err}`);
    }
    // results is an array consisting of messages collected during execution
    if (typeof(results) !== 'undefined') {
        logger.info(results);  // this is run at the end of the execution if it was an script
    }
});
```

Then I am wondering if there a way to redirect the logger with [`python_shell`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/python-shell)

**Note**: What I am currently using `exec`. But it has some drawbacks, if the node process is killed by forced, the python process become a zombie process. So this is not a good solution:

```js
// command is a string with the whole paths and arguments concatenating '>> `${debug_path}` 2>&1' at the end
shell = child_process.exec(command, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (error) {
        logger.error(`${error}`);
    }
    logger.info(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
    logger.info(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bokeh developers have added an option to redirect the output logger directly

```
> bokeh serve --help

[...]

--log-level LOG-LEVEL
                    One of: trace, debug, info, warning, error or critical
--log-format LOG-FORMAT
                    A standard Python logging format string (default:
                    '%(asctime)s %(message)s')
--log-file LOG-FILE   A filename to write logs to, or None to write to the
                    standard stream (default: None)
```